# Accessing properties of directive's isolated scope from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I'm trying to access the properties of my directive's isolated scope. Im slightly new to angularJS so I'm unsure if this is actually possible or not.

Below is my code:

```
    angular.module('myModule').directive('myDirective', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                require: 'ngModel',
                scope: {
                    type: '=',
                    fName: '=',
                    lName: '=',
                },
                templateUrl: '...'
            };
        }
    );

    angular.module(myModule).controller('myCtrl', [
        '$scope',
        function($scope) {
        $scope.openLink= function() {
            if ($scope.type === 'member') { //Here is where I want to access the type from the scope of the directive!
                $window.open('http://wwww.google.com, 'myWindow', 'menubar=0, width=600, height=680, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=180, left=350');
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

I would appreciate if someone could assist.

Many thanks

Comment: Isolated scope is isolated unless you make it public. The proper way to do this is with the use of a controller. Consult the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and research the use of the `controller` property on your directive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.you have to add 'type' property to your controller scope and you already passing 'type' to directive as value(refrence) and then set your 'type ' in directive either in link function or directive controller.

```
    angular.module(myModule).controller('myCtrl', [
            '$scope',
            function($scope) {
            $scope.type="";
            $scope.openLink= function() {
                if ($scope.type === 'member') { //Here is where I want to access the type from the scope of the directive!
                    $window.open('http://wwww.google.com, 'myWindow', 'menubar=0, width=600, height=680, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=180, left=350');
                }
            };
        }
angular.module('myModule').directive('myDirective', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                require: 'ngModel',
                scope: {
                    type: '=',
                    fName: '=',
                    lName: '=',
                },
                templateUrl: '...',
                controller:function($scope){
                  $scope.type="member";
                 }

            };
        }
    );
```